# Why **let (+) x y z = x + y + z in 5+6 7** is wrong?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

As shown in the title:

**let (+) x y z  = x + y + z in 5+6 7**

Why is this expression wrong?

The error says `Error: This expression is not a function; it cannot be applied`. But what I see is a function, it just redefine the operator of `+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're trying to call `6` with the argument `7` and `6` is not a function. Try

```
let (+) x y z = x + y + z in (5 + 6) 7
```

Comment: @JacksonTale Why is `1 + 2 * 3` different from `(1 + 2) * 3`?

Comment: Ok, I get it. So when OCaml tries to solve `5 + 6 7`, it first find out there is a space between 6 and 7, so it guesses it might be a function. function has the highest priority, so `6 7` gets served first, but it can't, because 6 is not a function. Am I right?

Comment: It doesn't guess and it doesn't care about spaces either: `(6)7` is still a function call. Function application simply has a higher priority than any (infix) operator, so `a b ? c d` is always parsed as `(a b) ? (c d)` for all operators `?` and values `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.

Comment: But how does OCaml know it is a possible function call?

Comment: Because you wrote two values next to each other (`6 7`) with no operator in between.